# App responsiveness poor using Application Analysis tool

Tags: windows-phone-8

When we test the application using 'Windows Phone Application Analysis tool' from visual studio, we were getting **application responsiveness poor** with red mark.

Please suggest on improving the performance of the app. Do we need to optimize the coding or need to change UI Design?

**Note:** Our application is business application. We have 15 pages and more functionalities for the application. We were using WCF Service to fetch data's from online and assigning to controls and saving data using WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Application responsiveness is an indication of how much CPU time your UI thread is taking. If the UI thread is doing too much work then touch and other UI events will be held up which makes for a bad user experience.

You will need to offload work from your UI thread to background threads wherever possible.

Comment: Kindly explain about 'Offload work from your UI thread to background thread'. If please provide me some samples for understanding about changing UI to background.

Comment: BackgroundWorker (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) or async/await should help. MSDN has loads of examples of both.

Comment: Is application analysis tool warning alert is a problem while launching application to Windows Phone Market Place?